How to find a sum of reciprocals of powers of two minus 1
I came across the following series while solving my math problem:
$$
\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^x - 1}
$$
While it's easy to check the convergence of the series, finding the sum itself seems to be tricky.
How to find the value of this sum?

It is less than $2$, see here. It is called the Erdös-Borwein constant, which is around $1.6066$.

This question is similar to: About the Erdős-Borwein Constant. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also this duplicate.

Thank you for a reference! The main difference is that I'm actually interested in derivation of the formula. However, I believe that given its name I will be able to find it on my own.
